# Django выдает ошибку на heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Я добавляю image в модель Post -

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True,unique=True, allow_unicode=True)
    body = models.TextField(db_index = False)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', blank=True, related_name='posts')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images_folder', blank=True)
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post_detail_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_update_url(self):
        return reverse('post_update_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    def get_delete_url(self):
        return reverse('post_delete_url', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = gen_slug(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)



    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пост'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Посты'
        ordering = ['-date_pub']
```

после этого я запускаю heroku bash -

```
heroku run bash
```

после чего я пишу -

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

после чего -

```
no migrations to apply
```

потом я иду на свой сайт и

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/hello/post/
column hello_post.image does not exist
LINE 1: ...title", "hello_post"."slug", "hello_post"."body", "hello_pos...
```

причем все посты с сайта я удалил

тaкже я пробовал `python3 manage.py migrate, python3 manage.py --fake, python3 manage.py migrate --fake default`

Нечего не помогает

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oQaH.png

Comment: Когда локально запускаете работает?

Comment: Вы точно создали базу данных именно из этих миграций, а не из каких-то других? Может, вам нужно очистить базу данных и пересоздать её с нуля?

Comment: Да, именно с этими миграциями.Не знаю может и сработает

Answer (score 0):

покажите вывод команды

`./manage.py showmigrations`

так как ваша проблема в любом случае связана с отсутствующем полем в БД, а значит не все миграции были применены. Возможно это вызвано тем что проект не был обновлен на сервере хероку, после его изменения локально.

Comment: Ошибку я уже исправил.Просто удалил мой текущий проект и заново копировал репозиторий. После этого миграции нормально запускались.Интересно,в чем проблема, ведь моя папка с проектом идентичная с репозиторием.